# Updating fields on one list from another

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list, workflow

I am using SharePoint 2013

I have 2 lists

List 1  There are many fields but the important ones for this question are

Employee (Person Picker)
Department (Choice Menu)
Division (Choice Menu)
Sub Division (Choice Menu)

List 2 (has only the following fields)

Employee (Person Picker)
Department (Choice Menu)
Division (Choice Menu)
Sub Division (Choice Menu)

I want to put in place a workflow that looks for the the matching employee on list 2 and fills in Department, Division and Sub Division on List 1.

However the Department, Division and Sub Division fields on List 1 must be set to cannot be blank - so therefore the workflow must start to work when the Employee field has been filled in on List 1 and not when the record has been saved.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**.

This is possible using SharePoint designer workflow.

1. Create/set required columns in your list 1.
2. Add workflow to list 1 on item created/changed.
3. Add IF condition in workflow to check if the employee exist in list 2 or not.
4. If employee is not in list 2 then add new item to list.
5. If employee exist in list 2 then update the item from list 2(Make sure your employee field is unique).

Comment: Hi Thanks for the Answer.

Will this work when the user instantly fills in the Employee field on List 1 or when the user Saves the record after completing all the fields in list 1?

Comment: Workflow will run after you create a new item in list or edit existing item in list. In both cases after you you fills all the fields on form of list 1 and submits the form by clicking on Save button.